# CAC graph and calculation

Tags: excel, graph, charts, statistics, cac

A nutrition plan app has a subscription that costs $10/month. The following chart gives average historical renewal rates for subscribers based on how many months they have been a subscriber.

Month and  Renewal rate
1st- 70%
2nd- 80%
3rd- 85%
4th and above-90%

How to Create a graph showing the time it takes to recoup advertising expenditure (PP - Payback Period) relative to the cost of acquiring a single subscriber (CAC - Customer Acquisition Cost).

I know that:
Payback period for customer= Customer acquisition cost/Revenue contributed in one year

CAC payback=Sales and marketing expenses in period/ (net new MRR Acquired in Period *Gross Margin)

there is formula for renewal [][1]][1]
What is the calculation I need to do here in order to create the graph?

Thank you

I did something like that:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

is it right?
[image]

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Scinana I'm stuck on Sales and marketing expenses in period which I don't know how to calculacte

Comment: @scinana I added a basic graph but I'm not sure what I need to do with the 10$

Comment: @scinana CAC payback for the first month=Sales and marketing expenses in period/ (net new MRR Acquired in Period *Gross Margin)= 1/70%*10=7$


CAC payback for the second month=2/80%*10 =25$